# How to get a particular item from the list?

Tags: scala

I have a list of a case class. I want to get a particular item from the list.

I do

```
myList.filter(_.id == myobject.id)(0)
```

This would work when the `filter` actually returns something. But when filter doesn't return anything I get an index out of bound exception.

```
scala> case class Color (id: Int, name: String)
defined class Color
scala> val myList1 = List[Color](Color(1, "red"), Color(2, "green"), Color(3, "blue"))
myList1: List[Color] = List(Color(1,red), Color(2,green), Color(3,blue))
scala> val toFind1 = Color(10, "white")
toFind1: Color = Color(10,white)
scala> myList1.filter(_.id == toFind1.id)(0)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could return an `Option[Color]` in order to gracefully handle items that can't be found.

In that case, I'd suggest using the [`find`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]) method as such:

```
// val colors = List[Color](Color(1, "red"), Color(2, "green"), Color(3, "blue"))
colors.find(_.id == 2)
// Some(Color(2,green))
colors.find(_.id == 5)
// None
```

If you'd rather return a `Color` rather than an `Option[Color]` you can always return a default value in case you can't find the `Color` in question:

```
colors.find(_.id == 5).getOrElse(Color(7, "purple"))
// Color(7,purple)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
a.find(_ == 0)
```

This way, if the filter operation results in an empty list, you will have a None.

In your specific example:

```
myList1.find(_.id == toFind1.id)
```

Now you have several options to continue with the operation:

1. Pattern match on `myList1.find(_.id == toFind1.id)
2. Get the result inside or provide a default value: `myList1.find(_.id == toFind1.id).getOrElse("DefaultValue")`
3. Use other transformations, like `myList1.find(_.id == toFind1.id).map(somFunc)` etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am passing the output from this to another method that expects `Color`. With this I'll have to change the signature of the method to accept `Option[Color]`. I can do that. But my next question is how can I change the body of that method? I've asked another question for it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890031/how-to-update-method-to-accept-option

Comment: You do not have to update your method, just extract the value of the `Option` if there was any, if it was `None` you do not call your method, since the `List` was empty.

Comment: `find` returns `Option`, so you don't need to call `headOption` because it won't do anything.

Comment: @Tim, I am sorry, I forgot to remove the `headOption` when I edited the answer to substitute `filter` by `find`. Now it is correct. Thanks for pointing it out.