# How to update method to accept Option

Tags: scala

I have a method like below:

```
private checkSomething(something: Color) {
  return something.name == "red" || something.type == "light"
}
```

This works ok, however, I would like to change it to `Option` like below:

```
private checkSomething(something: Option[Color]) {
  return something.name == "red" || something.type == "light"
}
```

but this breaks my method. How can I still call `something.name` and `something.light` ?

Comment: You shouldn't use  `return` in your methods.

Comment: The behavior of `checkSomething` is underspecified. What is supposed to happen if `something` is `None`? Should it return `true` or `false`? Furthermore: `type` doesn't compile like this, specified return types are invalid.

Answer (score 3):

it would be

```
private def checkSomething(something: Option[Color]) = {
   something.exists(s => s.name == "red" || s.`type` == "light")
}
```

your value is inside the Option monad so you need to use its methods to access it

I tried the code in a worksheet as I was pointed out some issues with it, basically you need an `=` sign before the opening bracket and return is unnecessary, also `type` is a reserved word, so you have to use backticks if you want to use it as a field name, but I'd rather choose a different name

Comment: Same here: `return` is unnecessary.

Comment: You’re right, I did a copy paste of his code in a rush

Comment: @Bruno You also need to fix the fact that this code returns `Unit` because it is using the procedure syntax. I have posted the corrected version so that it is available for others, but I'm happy to delete it if you fix your version,

Comment: Thank you all, I've tried the code in a worksheet this time!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking this referring to your other question ([How to get a particular item from the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889911/how-to-get-a-particular-item-from-the-list/53889961)), I think it isn't necessary to update your method to receive an `Option`, you could just do:

```
val result = myList1.find(_.id == toFind1.id).map(checkSomething)
```

with your first function definition, without passing in an `Option`

But, if you want to change your method signature, you can use @Tim implementation.

Comment: This is an answer to a different question.

Comment: Yeah, but he directed me from his previous question, so I thougt it wasn't necessary to make its method receive an `Option`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Bruno has the correct use of `Option` but does not fix the problem that the function returns `Unit` rather than `Boolean`. Here is the modified version:

```
private def checkSomething(something: Option[Color]) =
  something.exists(s => s.name == "red" || s.type == "light")
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use `Option.contains`,

```
scala> case class Color(name: String, `type`: String)
defined class Color

scala> def checkSomething(something: Option[Color]) = 
          something.map(_.name).contains("red") || something.map(_.`type`).contains("light")
checkSomething: (something: Option[Color])Boolean
```

usage,

```
scala> checkSomething(Some(Color("red", "light")))
res2: Boolean = true

scala> checkSomething(Some(Color("blue", "light")))
res3: Boolean = true

scala> checkSomething(Some(Color("blue", "dark")))
res4: Boolean = false
```

Also, you don't need `return` at the end.